# Select element within $(this) - jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have an animation of a div expanding apwards revealing more text however I want to show some hidden elements. How would I select these?

Javascript to perform the expanding div:

```
$(".act-details").bind('mouseover mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height : '160px',
        bottom : '180px'
    }, {
        queue : false,
        duration : 400,
        easing : 'swing'
    })
});
```

The HTML for the divs:

```
<li>
    <img src="_img/featured/act_images/text.png"/>
    <p class="name"><? echo $act_data['act_name'];?></p>                        
    <div class="act-details">
        <p>Cardiff - United Kingdom</p>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 3px;">House/Progressive</p>
        <p class="details-ext">Text the sliding div reveals</p>
        <a href="#">View Act...</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

The act-details div is the expanding one and the the hidden text is the "details-ext" class how would I select this within the javascript so I can unhide and hide it as needed.

Thanks.

Comment: `$('.details-ext', this).toggle()`

Comment: My problem is not that its hidden in the first place but their are multiple copies of this chunk of code... would using `$('.act-details)` perform this to every itteration of it or just to the one inside the selected div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).children('.details-ext').toggle();
```

This should work for you :)

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.details-ext' , this)
```

This will search for the class `.details-txt` in the context of `this`.